# Adding Particle System through blender script

Tags: scripting, particles

I am trying to make a particle system through the blender script, but I am unable to do so. I do not know much about scripting in blender. This is what I have and could you tell me how I could create a system?

```
obj = context.active_object
if len(obj.particle_systems) == 0:
        obj.modifiers.new("part", type='PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = "part")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `modifier_apply()` only works for those modifiers that have an *Apply* button, but when you add a *Particle System* as a modifier the only button on the modifier is *Convert*, which calls `bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()` , that's probably what you want instead of Apply.

Something like this:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

if len(obj.particle_systems) == 0:
    obj.modifiers.new("part", type='PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
    part = obj.particle_systems[0]

    settings = part.settings
    settings.emit_from = 'VERT'
    settings.physics_type = 'NO'
    settings.particle_size = 0.1
    settings.render_type = 'OBJECT'
    settings.dupli_object = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
    settings.show_unborn = True
    settings.use_dead = True

    bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()
```

Comment: Where can I find the different values for the settings?

Comment: hover over them with the mouse in the UI

Comment: in the console, use tab for autocomplete